# Mysterious Location in Java stack trace

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

Like the example below, when I run the test case `testSortArrayNull()` in test class named `ComparatorAbstractTestCase`, a **RuntimeException** is thrown and the generated stack trace is as follows,

Here is the results of stack trace,

```
testSortArrayNull(org.apache.commons.io.comparator.CompositeFileComparatorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.016 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: null
  at org.apache.commons.io.comparator.AbstractFileComparator.sort(AbstractFileComparator.java:48)
  at org.apache.commons.io.comparator.CompositeFileComparator.sort(CompositeFileComparator.java:45)
  at org.apache.commons.io.comparator.ComparatorAbstractTestCase.testSortArrayNull(ComparatorAbstractTestCase.java:96)
  ...
```

Here is the partial code of test class `ComparatorAbstractTestCase`,

```
public abstract class ComparatorAbstractTestCase extends FileBasedTestCase {

    /** comparator instance */
    protected CompositeFileComparator comparator;
    ...
    @Test
    public void testSortArrayNull() {
        assertNull(comparator.sort((File[])null)); /** LINE 96 */
    }
    ...
 }
```

Here is the partial code of class `CompositeFileComparator`, which is extended with class `AbstractFileComparator`.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CompositeFileComparator extends AbstractFileComparator implements Serializable { /** LINE 45 */
    ... // no sort() method
}
```

Here is the partial code of class `AbstractFileComparator`, which has `sort()` method.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

abstract class AbstractFileComparator implements Comparator<File> {

    public File[] sort(final File... files) {
        if (files != null) {
            Arrays.sort(files, this);
        }
        if (files == null) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(); /** LINE 48 */
        }
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

From the above 3 code snippets, we can see that line 45 in class `CompositeFileComparator` is the position of class declaration, why does stack trace locate in this mysterious location? And is it meaningful for this line 45 appear in stack trace? Thanks for all kindly help :)

Comment: That's why it's called stack trace, to inform the programmer each details for the issue

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik, so why does stack trace record this line? Line 45 is the position of class declaration. I know the child class inherited the method `sort()` of its supper class, but I can not understand why stack trace locates here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your class `AbstractFileComparator` has package-only access. Even though the `sort` method inside it is `public`, it cannot be referred to from outside the package.

To allow other code to access the `sort` method through the public subclass `CompositeFileComparator`, the method `sort` is redeclared by the compiled inside the `CompositeFileComparator`. This is synthetic Java code that doesn't exist in your source file, so the compiler has to pick a line number for it.

The compiler that you used picked the line number of the class declaration. Other compilers (the compiler in my particular version of Eclipse, for example), pick line number 1. Since the method doesn't really exist in your source code, the line number is not meaningful.

The method generated by the compiler will just call the superclass version of the method.

If you don't want this to happen, you can make `AbstractFileComparator` a `public` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am only curious about the line number in stack trace, since the inherited method cannot found in the child class, so I think that the cause of exception should locate in the original method in super class.